# NetSNMPJ - How to use this in 64 bit Windows machine

Tags: java, windows, 64-bit, net-snmp, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am trying to run NetSNMPJ in 64 bit Windows machine. But unable to proceed. Getting the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\Sample\lib\netsnmpj.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform.

Could not find the netsnmpj library.
Please check your java.library.path setting.
Currently java.library.path is set to:  
D:\Sample\lib
```

As per the exception, clear that it is due to the usage of 32 bit dll in 64 bit.
How can I use NetSNMPJ in a 64 bit machine?

Is there any patch available? Or any other way to build? Please help me.

Comment: Using a 32bit JVM should solve it.

Comment: Is there any option to use netsnmpj in a 64bit machine with 64bit JVM?

Comment: Yes - use a 64 bit DLL. Based on this bug report https://sourceforge.net/p/netsnmpj/discussion/249640/thread/ecdc8338/ and the activity of the project http://netsnmpj.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/netsnmpj/JNISupport/ I would not expect that one exists. Mabye it's better to have a look for another library. After a quick search I found http://www.snmp4j.org/ .